# Cocos2d-x how to invoke functions right after Spawn action

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

i have simple animation that scale and move over time thogeter the only way i found to do it 
is using Spawn action
the problem is that i like to invoke function action right after the Spawn action done . 
and using it in the Spawn action will trigger the Func action all the time ..

```
auto action = Spawn::create(
        MoveTo::create( 0.5, Vec2(spriteW,v.y/2)),
        ScaleTo::create(0.5f,1.0f),      
        nullptr);

    pBonusContainer->runAction(action);
```

i need to invoke the

```
CallFunc::create( CC_CALLBACK_0(FontContainer::removeSignCallback,this,pToolsToRemove))
```

right after MoveTo and ScaleTo done its thing with Spawn

Answer (score 0):

i think using Sequence will do the job.

```
auto seq = Sequence::create(Spawn::create(
    MoveTo::create( 0.5, Vec2(spriteW,v.y/2)),
    ScaleTo::create(0.5f,1.0f),
    CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(FontContainer::removeSignCallback,this,pToolsToRemove)),      
    nullptr);
```

Run Sequence

```
pBonusContainer->runAction(seq);
```

Just tested and work fine for me ;)

Comment: issamux it will work ok, as duration for `MoveTo` and `ScaleTo` are equal. The question is does end of `Spawn` coincide with the  time when all actions are done?

Comment: Sequence run several actions after each others. After the first one finished, other one start...not sure i ll check this and comment here later.

Comment: I confirm that Spawn is considered done, once all actions in spawn are done!